# Pay pal integration using 3-rd party shopping cart MVC .NET core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to integrate pay pal into my custom cart. I have used information on official Pay Pal site for integration. I'm using my sandbox account for testing the payment. It dose not seem to work and I don't know what is causing the problem. When calling the pay Pal view it just returns pay pal error.
Here is the PayPalPartialView:

```
@{ 
    int count = 1;
}
<form class="paypalform" action="https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="sb-2mrjh7443549@personal.example.com">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_@count" value="@item.ProductName" />
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_@count" value="@item.Price" />
        <input type="hidden" name="quantity_@count" value="@item.Quantity" />
        count++;
    }
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
 
    <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

Also the cart index view:

```
@model CartViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Cart Overview";
}


@if (Model.CartItems.Count > 0)
{
    <h1>Cart Overview</h1>
    <div class="cartWrapper">
        <div class="cartbg d-none">
            <h3 class="text-center">Redirecting you to paypal...</h3>
            <img src="~/Images/ajax_loader.gif" />
        </div>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.ProductName</td>
                    <td>@item.Quantity</td>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-action="Add" asp-route-id="@item.ProductId" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">+</a>
                        <a asp-action="Decrease" asp-route-id="@item.ProductId" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">-</a>
                        <a asp-action="Remove" asp-route-id="@item.ProductId" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Remove</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>@item.Price.ToString("C2")</td>
                    <td>@Model.CartItems.Where(x => x.ProductId == item.ProductId).Sum(x => x.Quantity * x.Price).ToString("C2")</td>
                </tr>
            }
            <tr>
                <td class="text-right" colspan="4">Grand total: @Model.GrandTotal.ToString("C2")</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-right" colspan="4">
                    <a asp-action="Clear" class="btn btn-danger">Clear cart</a>
                    <a href="#"  class="btn btn-primary checkout">Checkout</a>
                    


                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <h3 class="display-4 text-center">Cart is empty</h3>

}
<partial name="~/Views/Cart/_PayPalPartial.cshtml" for="CartItems" />
@section Scripts{
    <script>
    $(function () {

        $("a.checkout").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("div.cartbg").removeClass("d-none");
            $.get("/cart/clear", {}, function () {

                $("form.paypalform").submit();
            });
            
        });

    });

    </script>

}
```

the cart controller:

```
using CmsShoppingCart.Infrastructure;
using CmsShoppingCart.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CmsShoppingCart.Controllers
{
    public class CartController : Controller
    {
        private readonly CmsSchoppingCartContext context;
        public CartController(CmsSchoppingCartContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }
        //GET /cart
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<CartItem> cart = HttpContext.Session.GetJson<List<CartItem>>("Cart") ?? new List<CartItem>();

            CartViewModel cartVM = new CartViewModel
            {
                CartItems = cart,
                GrandTotal = cart.Sum(x => x.Price * x.Quantity)
            };
            return View(cartVM);
        }
        //GET /cart/add/id
        public async Task<IActionResult> Add(int id)
        {
            Product product = await context.Products.FindAsync(id);
            List<CartItem> cart = HttpContext.Session.GetJson<List<CartItem>>("Cart") ?? new List<CartItem>();
            CartItem cartItem = cart.Where(x => x.ProductId == id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (cartItem == null)
            {
                cart.Add(new CartItem(product));
            }
            else
            {
                cartItem.Quantity += 1;
                product.Quantity--;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            HttpContext.Session.SetJson("Cart", cart);
            if(HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] != "XMLHttpRequest")
                return RedirectToAction("Index");



            return ViewComponent("SmallCart");
            
        }
        //GET /cart/decrease/id
        public async Task<IActionResult> Decrease(int id)
        {
            Product product = await context.Products.FindAsync(id);
            List<CartItem> cart = HttpContext.Session.GetJson<List<CartItem>>("Cart");
            CartItem cartItem = cart.Where(x => x.ProductId == id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (cartItem.Quantity > 1)
            {
                --cartItem.Quantity;
                product.Quantity++;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                cart.RemoveAll(x => x.ProductId == id);
            }
         
            if (cart.Count == 0)
            {
                HttpContext.Session.Remove("Cart");
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetJson("Cart", cart);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        //GET /cart/remove/id
        public IActionResult Remove(int id)
        {

            List<CartItem> cart = HttpContext.Session.GetJson<List<CartItem>>("Cart");

            cart.RemoveAll(x => x.ProductId == id);

            if (cart.Count == 0)
            {
                HttpContext.Session.Remove("Cart");
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetJson("Cart", cart);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        //GET /cart/clear
        public IActionResult Clear()
        {
            HttpContext.Session.Remove("Cart");



            // return RedirectToAction("Page", "Pages");
            //return Redirect("/");
            if (HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] != "XMLHttpRequest")
                return Redirect(Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString());

            return Ok();
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

Cart model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CmsShoppingCart.Models
{
    public class CartItem
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public decimal Total { get { return Quantity * Price; }  }
        public string Image { get; set; }

        public CartItem()
        {

        }
        public CartItem(Product product)
        {
            ProductId = product.Id;
            ProductName = product.Name;
            Price = product.Price;
            Quantity = 1;
            Image = product.Image;

        }
    }
    
}
```

And cart View model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CmsShoppingCart.Models
{
    public class CartViewModel
    {
        public List<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; }
        public decimal GrandTotal { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its too late but for someone who are wondering about this issue:

Change PayPal Sandbox Url to:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
```